# no member named 'EmptyDeleter' in 'v8::BackingStore' when building for Node 14

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm building [this code](https://github.com/tree-sitter/node-tree-sitter/blob/df27b821f56ec6ed18c5c5864867fe92c733f376/src/conversions.cc#L32-L42)

```cpp
  #if _MSC_VER && NODE_RUNTIME_ELECTRON && NODE_MODULE_VERSION >= 89
    v8::Local<v8::Object> bufferView;
    bufferView = node::Buffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), point_transfer_buffer, 0, 2 * sizeof(uint32_t)).ToLocalChecked();
    auto js_point_transfer_buffer = node::Buffer::Data(bufferView);
  #elif V8_MAJOR_VERSION >= 8
    auto backing_store = ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore(point_transfer_buffer, 2 * sizeof(uint32_t), BackingStore::EmptyDeleter, nullptr);
    auto js_point_transfer_buffer = ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), std::move(backing_store));
  #else
    auto js_point_transfer_buffer = ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), point_transfer_buffer, 2 * sizeof(uint32_t));
  #endif
```

with `npx prebuild -r --strip` and it builds for Electron 16 to 23 and Node 12, 16 and 18 but when building with

```bash
npx prebuild -t 14.0.0 --strip
```

I get this error:

```
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/tree_sitter/vendor/tree-sitter/lib/src/lib.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/tree_sitter.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/tree_sitter_runtime_binding/src/binding.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/tree_sitter_runtime_binding/src/conversions.o
../src/conversions.cc:38:114: error: no member named 'EmptyDeleter' in 'v8::BackingStore'
    auto backing_store = ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore(point_transfer_buffer, 2 * sizeof(uint32_t), BackingStore::EmptyDeleter, nullptr);
                                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/tree_sitter_runtime_binding/src/conversions.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I changed it to `#elif V8_MAJOR_VERSION >= 9` and all Node versions work now.

Answer (score 0):

`v8::BackingStore::EmptyDeleter` was added to V8 in commit [5cf02f0](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/5cf02f0f207c05cebce74b1a8f2d0fe2accc7df6), which was released as 8.3.9. So, to be safe don't use it before 8.4:

```cpp
  #if _MSC_VER && NODE_RUNTIME_ELECTRON && NODE_MODULE_VERSION >= 89
    v8::Local<v8::Object> bufferView;
    bufferView = node::Buffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), point_transfer_buffer, 0, 2 * sizeof(uint32_t)).ToLocalChecked();
    auto js_point_transfer_buffer = node::Buffer::Data(bufferView);
  #elif (V8_MAJOR_VERSION > 8 || (V8_MAJOR_VERSION == 8 && V8_MINOR_VERSION > 3))
    auto backing_store = ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore(point_transfer_buffer, 2 * sizeof(uint32_t), BackingStore::EmptyDeleter, nullptr);
    auto js_point_transfer_buffer = ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), std::move(backing_store));
  #else
    auto js_point_transfer_buffer = ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), point_transfer_buffer, 2 * sizeof(uint32_t));
  #endif
```